# Returned values of the same Core Reporting API metrics are varied with combinations of specifed metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to fetch some metrics values like `goalXXCompletions` and `goalXXConversionRate` via Core Reporting API, along with `region` and `regionId` dimensions.

However, when I also specify either `users` or `uniquePageviews` metrics, the queries' returned values are unexpectedly changed even if they have the same dimensions.

After some investigation, I have found:

- Returned values are changed when specifing `users` and `uniquePageviews`
- Returned values are NOT changed when specifing `sessions` and `pageviews`

from the results which specify only `goalXXCompletions` and `goalXXConversionRate`.

Can anyone please let me know why returned values happen to vary with target metrics combinations?

I had tried both Query Explorer and HTTP API requests, but results were same.

### UPDATE

Added an example of a raw response. These values of each `region`/`regionId` are varied with or without specifying `users`/`uniquePageviews`.

```
{
  "totalResults": 28,
  "containsSampledData": true,
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "ga:regionId"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:region"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:users"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:goal1ConversionRate"
    }
  ],
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:users": "1125",
    "ga:goal1ConversionRate": "7.155222158107328"
  },
  "rows": [
    [
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "2",
      "0.0"
    ],
    [
      "21152",
      "Massachusetts",
      "358",
      "20.930232558139537"
    ],
    [
      "21176",
      "Texas",
      "463",
      "2.9797377830750893"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The above is not exactly the actual response, but almost the same except the count of the rows.

Comment: Where the results sampled? `containsSampledData: True`

Comment: Yes,  containsSampledData is true. I added an example response body I've got.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the hint. I've found that results contain samples only when I specify either users or uniquePageviews while not containing samples when specifying sessions and pageviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt mensioned in the comment, I found that this is because of the usage of sampled data.